# How to make Groovy arrays comparable?

Tags: collections, groovy, metaclass

Tried like this:

```
   ArrayList.metaClass.compareTo = {arg -> this?.size() <=> arg?.size() }  
   [1]<=>[2]
```

It doesn't work.

There is still exception rises `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot compare java.util.ArrayList with value '[1]' and java.util.ArrayList with value '[2]'`

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to implement the `Comparator` interface.

Another is to use the `metaClass` as you wanted, however you will not be able to use the `<=>` operator since `List` doesn't implement `Comparable`.

```
List.metaClass.compareTo = { Collection other ->
    delegate.size() <=> other?.size()
}

def x = [1, 2, 3]
def y = [4, 5]

println x.compareTo(y)  // but x <=> y won't work
```

Answer (score 0):

i should ask... why do you want to do that?
the comparison operators all depend on the class implementing Comparable and not just on the compareTo method, and i don't think it's possible to force that interface on an existing class.
afaik, you will need another approach

Answer (score 0):

You can mark list as Comparable:

```
List.metaClass.compareTo = { other ->
    delegate[0] <=> other[0]
}
assert ([1,2] as Comparable) <=> ([3,4] as Comparable) == -1
assert ([3,4] as Comparable) <=> ([1,2] as Comparable) == 1
assert ([3,4] as Comparable) <=> ([3] as Comparable) == 0
```